# How to filter a set of 2D points moving in a certain way

Tags: algorithm, matlab, geometry, physics, computational-geometry

I have a list of points moving in two dimensions (*x*- and *y*-axis) represented as rows in an array. I might have *N* points - i.e., *N* rows:

```
1 t1 x1 y1
2 t2 x2 y2
. 
.
.
N tN xN yN
```

where *ti*, *xi*, and *yi*, is the time-index, x-coordinate, and the y-coordinate for point i. The time index-index *ti* is an integer from 1 to *T*. The number of points at each such possible time index can vary from 0 to *N* (still with only *N* points in total).

My goal is the filter out all the points that do not move in a certain way; or to keep only those that do. A point must move in a *parabolic* trajectory - with *decreasing*  *x*- and *y*-coordinate (i.e., moving to the left and downwards only). Points with other dynamic behaviour must be removed.

Can I use a simple sorting mechanism on this array - and then analyse the order of the time-index? I have also considered the fact each point having the same time-index *ti* are physically distinct points, and so should be paired up with other points. The complexity of the problem grew - and now I turn to you.

NOTE: You can assume that the points are confined to a sub-region of the (x,y)-plane between two parabolic curves. These curves intersect only at only at one point: A point close to the origin of motion for any point.

**More Information**:

I have made some datafiles available:

- [MATLAB datafile (1.17 kB)](http://olebuus.web.surftown.dk/~misc/stackexchange/mat_points.mat)
- [same data as CSV with semicolon as column separator (2.77 kB)](http://olebuus.web.surftown.dk/~misc/stackexchange/mat_points.csv)

**Necessary context**:

The datafile hold one uint32 array with 176 rows and 5 columns. The columns are:

1. pixel x-coordinate in 175-by-175 lattice
2. pixel y-coordinate in 175-by-175 lattice
3. discrete theta angle-index
4. time index (from 1 to T = 10)
5. row index for this original sorting

The points "live" in a 175-by-175 pixel-lattice - and again inside the upper quadrant of a circle with radius 175. The points travel on the circle circumference in a counterclockwise rotation to a certain angle *theta* with horizontal, where they are thrown off into something close to a parabolic orbit. Column 3 holds a discrete index into a list with indices 1 to 45 from 0 to 90 degress (one index thus spans 2 degrees). The theta-angle was originally deduces solely from the points by setting up the trivial equations of motions and solving for the angle. This gives rise to a quasi-symmetric quartic which can be solved in close-form. The actual metric radius of the circle is 0.2 m and the pixel coordinate were converted from pixel-coordinate to metric using simple linear interpolation (but what we see here are the points in original pixel-space).

My problem is that some points are not behaving properly and since I need to statistics on the theta angle, I need to remove the points that certainly do NOT move in a parabolic trajoctory. These error are expected and fully natural, but still need to be filtered out.

**MATLAB plot code**:

```
% load data and setup variables:
load mat_points.mat;
num_r = 175;
num_T = 10;
num_gridN = 20;

% begin plotting:
figure(1000);
clf;
plot( ...
   num_r * cos(0:0.1:pi/2), ...
   num_r * sin(0:0.1:pi/2), ...
   'Color', 'k', ...
   'LineWidth', 2 ...
);
axis equal;
xlim([0 num_r]);
ylim([0 num_r]);
hold all;

% setup grid (yea... went crazy with one):
vec_tickValues = linspace(0, num_r, num_gridN);
cell_tickLabels = repmat({''}, size(vec_tickValues));
cell_tickLabels{1} = sprintf('%u', vec_tickValues(1));
cell_tickLabels{end} = sprintf('%u', vec_tickValues(end));
set(gca, 'XTick', vec_tickValues);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', cell_tickLabels);
set(gca, 'YTick', vec_tickValues);
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', cell_tickLabels);
set(gca, 'GridLineStyle', '-');
grid on;

% plot points per timeindex (with increasing brightness):
vec_grayIndex = linspace(0,0.9,num_T);
for num_kt = 1:num_T
   vec_xCoords = mat_points((mat_points(:,4) == num_kt), 1);
   vec_yCoords = mat_points((mat_points(:,4) == num_kt), 2);
   plot(vec_xCoords, vec_yCoords, 'o', ...
      'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', ...
      'MarkerFaceColor', vec_grayIndex(num_kt) * ones(1,3) ...
   );
end
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: How your data structured for the time change? If one point is a row, does it has only one `x` and one `y`? Do you have more columns or the 3rd dimension? Or is it actually a cell array and each `t_i`, `x_i`, `y_i` are vectors?

Comment: @yuk My data is a normal 2d array in MATLAB. The columns are as mentioned in the question. The array is uint32 and each value is an index into pixel space for the points and time is as described (an integer from 1 to T).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why, it looks almost as if you're simulating a radar tracking debris from the collision of two missiles...

Anyway, let's coin a new term: **object**. Objects are moving along parabolae and at certain times they may emit flashes that appear as **points**. There are also other points which we are trying to filter out.

We will need some more information:

1. Can we assume that the objects obey the physics of things falling under gravity?

   Must every object emit a point at every timestep during its lifetime?

   Speaking of lifetime, do all objects begin at the same time? Can some expire before others?

   How precise is the data? Is it exact? Is there a measure of error? To put it another way, do we understand how poorly the points from an object might fit a perfect parabola?

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. Actually the objects ares just seeds (cereals) moving in an laboratory-scaled sorting machine. I am analysing the machines ability to separate two seed species (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi-5wpw_oGM). The answers are: 1: yes (only gravity, no drag introduced as of now); 2: no; 3: there is no general law; 4: the parabolic trajectory is an assumption - hopefully a useful one. I find it unlikely that this assumption could be the cause of any extreme error/outliers (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data with (index,time) as keys and for all locations of a point i see if they follow parabolic trajectory?

Which part are you facing problem? Sorting should be very easy. IMHO, it is the second part (testing if a set of points follow parabolic trajectory) that is difficult.

Comment: You are right - sorting is certainly not the problem. It is indeed the second part. I guess it would useful if one could devise an algorithm that, in a list of numers, could find sorted subsets of a minimum size of 2. But have not had the time myself.